# Не могу вставить значения в псевдоэлемент через var()

Tags: css3, html5, sass

HTML

```
<div class="category">
    <img src="<?php echo PATH_IMG .'/type/computer.png'?>" alt="computer">
    <h2>Computer</h2>
    <div class="description">
        <h2>1092<span class="pcs">pcs.</span></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="chart" style="--chart-percent: 90%;"></div>
</div>
```

Sass

```
.chart
    width: var(--chart-percent)
    height: 16px
    border-radius: 12px
    margin-right: auto
    background-color: red
    position: relative
    &::before
        content: var(--chart-percent)
        position: absolute
        left: 50%
        top: calc(50% + 0.25px)
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
        white-space: nowrap
        font-weight: 600
        font-size: 0.8rem
        color: var(--color-white)
```

Почему не вставляется значение в ::before через var(--chart-percent)?

Comment: Строка для content должна быть в кавычках, а у вас `90%` без кавычек

Comment: Это то понятно, как сделать чтобы она вставлялась то

Comment: Тем более я сейчас почитал, и ваш коментарий @andreymal не верный, много есть использованей без кавычек, вот один из них(content: attr(href);) где спокойнно вставляется без ""/ content: url(image.png); так-же без кавычек content: var(--icon); так-же у других вставляется без проблем!
Все информация от сюда
1. https://codersblock.com/blog/diving-into-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements/
2. https://webformyself.com/ubrat-var-css-iz-root/

Comment: Но в вашей переменной `--chart-percent` нет никаких attr или url, непонятно зачем вы вообще их сюда приплели. Если вы напишете что-то вроде `--chart-percent: attr(data-percent)` — тогда да, конечно работать будет. Но вы же туда написали не attr и не url, а `90%` — в нём нет attr, нет url и нет кавычек, а значит это значение **некорректно** для стиля content

Comment: Почитайте, например, [полный синтаксис значения content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#syntax) — значение `90%` не подходит ни под один из допустимых вариантов

Comment: Я привел примы где используется без "", я так-же видел у других людей как они вставляют контент через var() в ::befor сказать точно не могу как они вставляли так-как не помню, но помню что они использовали var()

Comment: В вашей первой ссылке есть пример `content: 'This is after!';` — он правильный с кавычками. В вашей второй ссылке есть пример `content: "\f14a";` — он тоже правильный тоже с кавычками. Там же во второй ссылке есть такой пример `content: var(--icon);` и значения переменных `--icon: var(--checkbox);` и далее `--checkbox: "\f14a";` — вот это да, опять кавычки! Я не понимаю, зачем вы отрицаете очевидное: **нужны кавычки!**

Comment: Да же если и нужны дело не в этом, я бы хотел узнать решение, как я могу значение в процентах вставлять в width чтобы оно работало, и так-же в элемент before для тектса

Comment: А вот с этим проблема: [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751778) и [вот там](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949143) пишут, что решения не существует. Наверное, лучшее, что можно предложить, — это заводить две переменные: одну без кавычек, другую с кавычками